# How to prevent multiple login in Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, session, spring-security

I have below spring security configuration. When I add session-management attribute after first successfull login and logout, I can't login again. It redirects me to authentication-failure-url. If I remove it, it works fine. I can rejoin successfully. What am I doing wrong with session-management?

```
    <http auto-config='false' use-expressions="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/login" access="permitAll"/>        
    <intercept-url pattern="/j_spring_security_check" access="permitAll"/>
    <logout logout-success-url="/login.xhtml" invalidate-session="true" delete-cookies="JSESSIONID"/>        
    <form-login login-page="/login.xhtml"
                login-processing-url="/j_spring_security_check"                                                       
                default-target-url="/pages/index.xhtml"
                always-use-default-target="true"                                                                            
                authentication-failure-url="/login.xhtml?error=true"/>
    <custom-filter before="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" ref="customAjaxControlFilter" />
    <session-management invalid-session-url="/login.xhtml">
        <concurrency-control error-if-maximum-exceeded="true" max-sessions="1" expired-url="/login.xhtml"/>            
    </session-management>
</http>
```

Comment: Please check [this FAQ](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/faq/faq.html#faq-session-listener-missing).

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have added the listener to your web.xml file. It is essential to make sure that the Spring Security session registry is notified when a session is destroyed. Without it, the session information will not be removed from the registry.

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.security.ui.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher</listener-class>
</listener>
```